# Node.js Module - attach required objects methods to main App object

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm

Sorry if the title is a little vague, I don't really know what to call this concept.

Basically I have a main.js file that contains the following code:

```
var util = require('./folder/util');
var summoner = require('./folder/player');

var App = {
  timeout: 500,
  apiKey: 'asdnanfasofafasqrqrsa',
  region: 'can'
}

App.init = function(apiKey, region) {
  this.apiKey = apiKey;
  this.region = region;
}

App.getPlayerByName = player.getPlayerByName;

module.exports = App;
```

I also have a player.js file that contains those methods (player.getPlayerByName). My goal is to create an NPM module with that main.js entry file and access it like so:

```
var main = require('main.js');

main.getPlayerByName('Jake');
```

Now the only way I've found to 'attach' those methods to that main App object so I can access it as above, is by adding the following line of code to main.js:

```
App.getPlayerByName = player.getPlayerByName;
```

It works great as is, but after I add a lot more methods to the player.js file I will have a lot of extra bloat in the main.js file that I wouldn't mind avoiding. Is there a better way of going about this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the player object and copy all methods over to your `App` object:

```
var App = {
  timeout: 500,
  apiKey: 'asdnanfasofafasqrqrsa',
  region: 'can'
}

App.init = function(apiKey, region) {
  this.apiKey = apiKey;
  this.region = region;
}

// copy all methods from player to App
for (var method in player) {
    if (player.hasOwnProperty(method) && typeof player[method] === "function") {
        App[method] = player[method];
    }
}
```

This will work as long as `player` is just a namespace object, where the methods don't use the actual object instance.

---

Or, you could just use the existing `player` object and assign your own properties to that existing object:

```
Object.assign(player, {
    timeout: 500,
    apiKey: 'asdnanfasofafasqrqrsa',
    region: 'can',
    init: function(apiKey, region) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.region = region;
    }
});

module.exports = player;
```

In both these cases, you have to make sure that there are no method/property name conflicts between the two uses of the object.

Comment: First solution was exactly what I was looking for, thank you